# Let $E, A \subset X$. Show that $\partial_A(E\cap A) \subset A \cap \partial E$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $E, A \subset X$. Show that $\partial_A(E\cap A) \subset A \cap \partial E$.

By definition $$\partial_A(E \cap A) = cl_A(E\cap A) \cap cl_A(A \setminus(E\cap A)) \\ = cl_A(E \cap A) \cap cl_A(A \setminus E). $$

Now take $x \in \partial_A(E \cap A) \implies x \in cl_A(E) \cap cl_A(A)$ and $x \in cl_A(A \setminus E)$.

Now from the fact that $x \in cl_A(A) \implies x \in A$.

So we’re left to show that $x \in \partial E$

It seems that there is an alternative definition that says that $$\partial_A(E \cap A) = \{a \in A : U_a \cap E \ne \emptyset \text{ and } U_a \cap E^c \ne \emptyset \}$$ where $U_a$ is open in $A$.

So I would need to show that for any nbdh $U_x$ the two conditions hold.

Since $x\in cl_A(A \setminus E) \implies \exists U_x $ such that $U_x \cap (A \setminus E) = U_x \cap E^c \ne \emptyset$, but I cannot seem to find how I can get to the other condition that $U_x \cap E \ne \emptyset$?

Edit:

I didn’t notice but clearly $x \in E$ also since $x \in cl_A(E)$. Now woudln’t this imply that $U_x \cap E$ is non-empty which would finish the problem?

Answer (score 1):

First, $E\subseteq A$ is not supposed, so $cl_A(E)$ makes no sense, nevertheless $x\in cl_A(E\cap A)$ implies $x\in A$.

Note that $cl_A(B)=cl(B)\cap A$ for any $B\subseteq A$.

Using this, if $x\in\partial_A(E\cap A)$, then $x\in cl(E\cap A)\cap A\,\cap\,cl(A\setminus E)\cap A$.

Since the closure operator is monotone (as preserves intersection), we have $cl(E\cap A)\subseteq cl(E)$ and $cl(A\setminus E)\subseteq cl(X\setminus E)$, so
$$x\in cl(E)\cap cl(X\setminus E)\,\cap\,A\ =\ \partial E\cap A$$
follows.

You can try to do the same proof by the other definition involving the existence of a particular open neighborhood.

Comment: It’s weird that even though $cl_A(E)$ doesn’t mean anything, it can be still deduced by the properties of the closure here?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Well, the subscript $A$ means that we're restricting to subspace $A$. The argument and the result of $cl_A$ should both be subsets of $A$.